# access fields from a dexterity behavior on a content type invariant check

Tags: plone, behavior, dexterity, z3c.form

I have a behavior that defines two fields: `year` and `week` (of the year).

This behavior is reused for several content types, and only in one of them I need to make sure that this fields are not repeated in any other instance of the same content type, i.e. two objects of this content type can not share the same `year` **and** `week` (is fine to share the same year *or* the same week).

As this restriction is only meant for this specific content type I tried with an `zope.interface.invariant` but for some reason I can not get access to the fields defined in the behavior.

A simplified version of the Content type would be:

```
class IMyContentType(form.Schema)
    title = schema.TextLine(title="My title",
                            description="My description",
                            required=True,
    )

    @invariant
    def check_year_and_week(data):
        data.week
```

How can I get the value (if any) from within `check_year_and_week` invariant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Invariants have access to values for other fields in the same interface, but not fields from other interfaces.

You can use a widget manager validator instead: http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/validation.html#widget-manager-validators

Or do the validation in your form's action handler: http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/validation.html#validating-in-action-handlers

Answer (score 0):

A behavior is nothing but an adapter; if you're not getting the fields on the invariant you probably need adapt your content type before trying to access the extra fields.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Where should I do this adaptation? The behavior is added to the content type on its fti (.xml file), is that a problem?

Comment: An interesting problem. The "data" variable for the invariant would not have anything to adapt.